# Spring Boot : Localize REST API response

Tags: spring-boot, localization, internationalization, locale

I am able to localize the String using Locale Resolver and Interceptor method. The translation file have **KEY** as prefix.primaryKey.fieldName.

For example,

> public class A {
>
> private String x;
>
> private String y;
>
> }

The key will be :

> prefix.primaryKey.x
>
> prefix.primaryKey.y

I am able to localize the same using Reflection, by getting field name and field value.

Is there any other way i don't have to use reflection? Or any other standard ways?